# Calling a function with pointers

Tags: c, loops, pointers

I've been staring at the same code for hours and I just need another person to proof read it because I cant figure out the problem anymore ive probably read my 1000 line code a hundred times already. This is the chunk with the problem. I know the solution is probably an extra * or & but i just need help finding it. I would really appreciate it thanks.

My error says:

```
Cannot convert int** to int* for argument 1 to void dayCheck(int*, int*, float*, float*, int, int, float*, char*, char*)
```

```
void restDayCheck(float *, float *, char *, char *);

void dayCheck(int *, int *, float *, float *, int, int, float *, char *,
              char *);

void timeLoop(int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, float *, int *, int *, float *,
              float *);

void restDayCheck(float *totalSalary, float *hourlyRate, char *restAns,
                  char *restWorkAns) {
  do {
    printf("\n\tIs this day a rest day? [y/n] : ");
    scanf(" %c", restAns);
    printf("\n\tDid you work on this day? [y/n] : ");
    scanf(" %c", restWorkAns);
    if (*restAns != 'y' || *restAns != 'Y' || *restAns != 'n' ||
        *restAns != 'N')
      printf("Answer/s are invalid.");
  } while (*restAns != 'y' || *restAns != 'Y' || *restAns != 'n' ||
           *restAns != 'N');
}

void timeLoop(int *startMonth, int *startDate, int *endMonth, int *endDate,
              int *totalDays, float *totalSalary, int *shiftHours,
              int *shiftMins, float *hourlyRate, float *minRate, char *restAns,
              char *restWorkAns) {
  // VARIABLES
  int timeIN, timeOUT;
  int newDate, newMonth, i;
  // int x, y; extra if i need
  float restDayPay = (*hourlyRate * 8) * 0.30;

  printf("\n \t \tCLOCKING IN\n");
  // LOOP
  for (i = 0; i >= *totalDays; i++) {
    float OTrate = *hourlyRate * 0.25;
    if (*startMonth == 1 || *startMonth == 3 || *startMonth == 5 ||
        *startMonth == 7 || *startMonth == 8 || *startMonth == 10 ||
        *startMonth == 12) {

      do {
        printf("\n\tDate : %d/%d", *startMonth, *startDate);
        do {
          printf("\n \tEnter Time-In (Military Time 0000-2359): ");
          scanf("\t%d", &timeIN);
          if (timeIN < 0 || timeIN > 2359)
            printf("\n \t Time-In is invalid (Military time ONLY)");
        } while (timeIN < 0 || timeIN > 2359);

        do {
          printf("\n \tEnter Time-Out (Military Time 0000-2359): ");
          scanf("\t%d", &timeOUT);
          if (timeOUT < 0 || timeOUT > 2359)
            printf("\n \t Time-Out is invalid (Military time ONLY)");
        } while (timeOUT < 0 || timeOUT > 2359);

        computeTotalHours(timeIN, timeOUT, shiftHours, shiftMins);
        restDayCheck(totalSalary, hourlyRate, restAns, restWorkAns);
        dayCheck(&startDate, &startMonth, &hourlyRate, &minRate, timeIN,
                 timeOUT, &totalSalary, &shiftHours, &shiftMins, &restAns,
                 &restWorkAns);

        *startDate = *startDate + 1;
        // TEMPORARY to check if it worked
        printf("\n\tTotal Hours: %d\n", *shiftHours);
        printf("\n\tTotal Minutes: %d\n", *shiftMins);

      } while (*startDate <
               32); // less than 32 to limit date of the months to 31
    }

    if (*startMonth == 2) {
      do {
        printf("\n\tDate : %d/%d", *startMonth, *startDate);
        do {
          printf("\n \tEnter Time-In (Military Time 0000-2359): ");
          scanf("\t%d", &timeIN);
          if (timeIN < 0 || timeIN > 2359)
            printf("\n \t Time-In is invalid (Military time ONLY)");
        } while (timeIN < 0 || timeIN > 2359);

        do {
          printf("\n \tEnter Time-Out (Military Time 0000-2359): ");
          scanf("\t%d", &timeOUT);
          if (timeOUT < 0 || timeOUT > 2359)
            printf("\n \t Time-Out is invalid (Military time ONLY)");
        } while (timeOUT < 0 || timeOUT > 2359);

        computeTotalHours(timeIN, timeOUT, shiftHours, shiftMins);
        restDayCheck(totalSalary, hourlyRate, restAns, restWorkAns);
        dayCheck(&startDate, &startMonth, &hourlyRate, &minRate, timeIN,
                 timeOUT, &totalSalary, &shiftHours, &shiftMins, &restAns,
                 &restWorkAns);

        *startDate = *startDate + 1;

        // TEMPORARY to check if it worked
        printf("\n\tTotal Hours: %d\n", *shiftHours);
        printf("\n\tTotal Minutes: %d\n", *shiftMins);

      } while (*startDate < 29); // since 28 is the total days in february, less
                                 // than 29 to limit the days
    }

    if (*startMonth == 4 || *startMonth == 6 || *startMonth == 9 ||
        *startMonth == 11) {
      do {
        printf("\n\tDate : %d/%d", *startMonth, *startDate);
        do {
          printf("\n \tEnter Time-In (Military Time 0000-2359): ");
          scanf("\t%d", &timeIN);
          if (timeIN < 0 || timeIN > 2359)
            printf("\n \t Time-In is invalid (Military time ONLY)");
        } while (timeIN < 0 || timeIN > 2359);

        do {
          printf("\n \tEnter Time-Out (Military Time 0000-2359): ");
          scanf("\t%d", &timeOUT);
          if (timeOUT < 0 || timeOUT > 2359)
            printf("\n \t Time-Out is invalid (Military time ONLY)");
        } while (timeOUT < 0 || timeOUT > 2359);

        computeTotalHours(timeIN, timeOUT, shiftHours, shiftMins);
        restDayCheck(totalSalary, hourlyRate, restAns, restWorkAns);
        dayCheck(&startDate, &startMonth, &hourlyRate, &minRate, timeIN,
                 timeOUT, &totalSalary, &shiftHours, &shiftMins, &restAns,
                 &restWorkAns);

        *startDate = *startDate + 1;

        // TEMPORARY to check if it worked
        printf("\n\tTotal Hours: %d\n", *shiftHours);
        printf("\n\tTotal Minutes: %d\n", *shiftMins);
      } while (*startDate < 31); // 31 is less than 30 which is the total days
                                 // in the months listed in the if statement
    }

    *startMonth = *startMonth + 1;
  }
}

void dayCheck(int *startDate, int *startMonth, float *hourlyRate,
              float *minRate, int timeIN, int timeOUT, float *totalSalary,
              int *shiftHours, int *shiftMins, char *restAns,
              char *restWorkAns) {}
```

I did not include the code in dayCheck anymore because my error is with calling the function. Thanks so much again.

Ive tried pretty much everything. I know my error is just something ive overlooked or skipped. I just need another set of eyes tbh.

Comment: The error message should be very clear. Please try to understand what it says.

Comment: `dayCheck(&startDate, &startMonth, &hourlyRate, &minRate, timeIN, timeOUT, &totalSalary, &shiftHours, &shiftMins, &restAns, &restWorkAns);` the first parameter `startDate` is already an `int*` you don't need or want an `int**` so get rid of the `&` with this said why are you passing by pointer in `c++` instead of using pass by reference? The entire code looks like you are not learning `c++` at all. Instead you are learning `c` and may be using a `c++` compiler to compile it.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you. I'm fairly new to coding and still messing up with pointers. I'll remove the &.

Comment: You'll find pointers aren't hard. It's book-keeping that's hard.

Comment: I recommend making use of structs (or classes, if this is actually C++): This allows you to reduce the number of parameters to pass and e.g. start/end date+month would combine to a object quite naturally...